# Limit Spring Security Remember Me to Certain URLs

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I'm using the Groovy/Grails Spring Security plugin and I'm wondering if is it possible to limit the URLs that will allow (or trigger) the Remember Me auto login functionality?  I have a custom (somewhat complicated) implementation of the RememberMeService and it's autoLogin method gets called for every single request (including asset files like .css, .js, .jpg, etc.).  Is there a way to provide a filter and only have the remember me functionality invoked for certain URLs (in my case all except assets)?

Comment: Why don't you just exclude the static assets from the filter chain? This is generally recommended anyway.

Comment: That's a good idea ... if you have any suggestions on how to do that I would welcome any information or examples.